# Etiquette for wearing ties at a "Black Tie" event

Tags: etiquette, united-kingdom, non-verbal-communication

I've been invited to a wedding (in Scotland, UK). It's described as a "Black-tie" event and the groom has asked guests to wear a dinner jacket (tuxedo), but it's not an absolute requirement. A few guests will be wearing suits, and I plan to do the same.

For guests wearing a dinner jacket, they will be wearing black bow ties, which is the expected accompaniment.

My question is: is there etiquette about what colour and type of tie to wear when attending a "black tie" but not actually wearing a dinner jacket?

Should the tie be a bow tie?  (That may look a bit half-baked.)

Should the tie also be black?  (That may look like I am attending a funeral, which is something I'd want to avoid unless it's the expected look, but it would match the general colour theme.)

Or is there no expected standard and I can wear whatever colour tie I like?

Comment: My previous question, which was essentially the same as this, was closed as it was suggested that I was seeking "fashion advice".  This is not the case.  I'm already anxious about turning up in a suit rather than a dinner jacket, and I'd rather not make a faux pas regarding my tie!  This is genuine question about the expected standard of dress at a "black tie" event.

Comment: Advice for next time on any SE site: [edit] your existing posts, never post a new one. If the new ones aren't good enough either, you may run into the automated quality bans that no mod can lift.

Comment: *"is there etiquette"* - ask the groom about that. He has expectations and basically it's his opinion that judges you being dressed appropriately or not. You have no benefit from anyone's opinion here if your appearance doesn't fit into this particular event with its particular kind of rules. *" This is genuine question"* - really? To me it sounds as it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not wear a black tie. Best would be a conservative bow tie with a suit. You can also wear an ordinary tie. It should just match the suit and be mature and have a certain amount of gravitas.

Basically the formal situation (if that is what it is) is such that the tone is serious and respectful, so you want to reflect that in your choice of suit and tie. Like what you would wear to church.

Comment: Hi Tyler! As it stands currently, your answer lacks backup as [explained in the site's citation policy](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-ips-stack-exchange). Please take a minute to read [how to write a good answer](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer) and improve your post accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I agree that wearing a black suit and tie is more suitable for a funeral  than a wedding reception. The affair sounds rather grand, I'd visit the venue's website, you should be able to tell if you need to to be dressed really smartly and perhaps even consider getting a good haircut.

Overall, [a dark suit](https://www.gentlemansgazette.com/tuxedo-black-tie-guide/etiquette/black-tie-optional-dress-code/#:%7E:text=Traditionally%2C%20a%20dark%20suit%20with,without%20actually%20being%20a%20tuxedo.), navy blue or dark grey, with a matching dark tie will do. (source: *Gentlemen's Gazette*)

For a touch of colour and class, a [silk pocket square](https://threebuttons.sg/blogs/tailors/pocket-square) will give you that confidence to stand your own ground among the black bowtie wearers.

> **Weddings and formal events**
> Choosing the right pocket square in these events depend on the dress code and colour theme. For formal events that are a little more celebratory (such as weddings), you can afford to wear a pocket square that adds a pop of colour to your suit.

[image: Image of a discreet pocket square in a men's breast pocket]
<sub>Snippet interview with [Dylan Ang](https://threebuttons.sg/) and image courtesy of *Three Buttons*</sub>

The most important thing is to enjoy your look and feel comfortable. Confidence is everything, and I guarantee no one will care what you are wearing as long as you don't stick out like a sore thumb, which you won't. Relax.

Comment: You can get by with a dark suit but something beyond “office” helps—bow tie (not nec. black) and pocket handkerchief and maybe even French cuffs might work. So does military dress uniform, if you’re in the military.